# Why is this simple Box2D thing not working?

Tags: java, box2d, processing

When I run this, nothing happens. The block stays at (10.0,-10.0) and doesn't fall. Why?

Here's my code:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.PolygonShape;
import org.jbox2d.common.Vec2;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.Body;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.BodyDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.FixtureDef;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.World;  

public class PhysicsWorld extends PApplet {
    
    private World world;
    private Body block;
    private static final float RATIO = 30f;
    
    public void createWorld() {
        Vec2 gravity = new Vec2(0.f,-9.8f);
        world = new World(gravity, true);
        world.setGravity(gravity);
        
    }
    
    private void createBlock(){
        BodyDef blockDef;
        PolygonShape blockShape;
        
        blockDef = new BodyDef();
        blockDef.position.set(300.f / RATIO, -300.f / RATIO);
        
        blockShape = new PolygonShape();
        blockShape.setAsBox(20/RATIO, 25/RATIO);
        
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = blockShape;
        fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
        fixtureDef.friction = 0.8f;
        fixtureDef.restitution = 0.3f;
        
        block = world.createBody(blockDef);
        block.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    }
    
    public void setup(){
        createWorld();
        createBlock();
    }
    
    public void draw(){
        world.step(1/60, 8, 3);
        //world.clearForces();
        System.out.println(block.getPosition() +" " + world.getGravity());
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bodies are static by default, so you just need to set the body type to b2_dynamicBody.

Comment: I did this:

    blockDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;

and it still doesn't work. What do?

Comment: you do that before you create the body right? What do you get if you print out the body type in the draw function?

Comment: Arg, I wish I had seen your comment. Yes, this is what it was; I was setting the type after createBody() when it should have been before.